# get possible instance/type of object

Tags: java

I have the problem that a given object could be one of several different objects (like files in a directory, that could be sound, image, text, ...)
Is there the possibility to find out the type of the object beside from the 'instanceof' operator?
Couse that would result in an endless if - then row ...

Comment: A use case would be helpful here. What would you do with this information? You may end up with an endless if-else construct anyway.

Comment: Sounds like polymorphism might help here (perhaps with wrapper objects).

Comment: its just for debugging. to be sure if the right object is given.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`foo.getClass()` gets the [`java.lang.Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object describing the class of the object.